# Syncing 2 repositories with different histories

Tags: git

So I currently have 2 repos:

repoA:branchA

repoB:branchB

Codewise they're identical, but the history on the branches are diff. When I do work I do purely in repoB:branchB (so open a PR, get approved, merge). After that's done I want to mirror that "merge" commit over to repoA:branchA. How would I get this done? Considering they have different histories? Maybe I can just cherry pick a commit? So overall, I want to sync repoA:branchA and repoB:branchB even though they have different histories. I just need specific commits copied over from repoB:branchB to repoA:branchA.

Thank you!

Comment: just do the work on both of them:P

Comment: The code is the same on both, so instead of having to manually copy over the changes in the merge, i was hoping git have something already built in which will allow me to do this

Comment: Github already has this feature. "Merge Commits"

But its for 1 Repository that has 2 Branches.

Just move alll the seperate files into a new Branch on RepoA
Rather than having 2 Repos and 2 Branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History, in Git, *is* the commits in the repository.  History is formed by taking the *last* commit in each branch—as found by the branch's name—and working backwards through the backwards-pointing chain, in which each commit identifies its parent by hash ID.  All the commits that you can reach in this way, or from any other name, such as a tag name, are part of the repository.  For more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

You can make a repository with multiple different histories—different, disconnected graphs—by using `git fetch` to a remote or URL with the other history.  These histories are difficult to *merge*, because of the lack of common ancestors, but `git cherry-pick` still works on them.  Pick a commit, use `git cherry-pick` to treat its immediate parent as a sort of merge base, and Git will do a three-way merge between that commit's parent, that commit, and your current commit.

Hence, if you're in repo A, and the change you want is in repo B between commits *P* and *C* (where *C* is the child), you might run:

```
git fetch <url-of-repo-B>
git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>
```

Note that this brings in the entire history from repository B.  That's harmless, except for the fact that your repository will temporarily be much bigger.  Eventually, these commits, if unreferenced, will age out and be garbage collected.